# SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle throws array_combine error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have a many-to many relation which is throwing a warning:

```
Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle/Model/ModelManager.php line 179
```

The admin class in question was working fine until updated SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle to version 2.2.4 with composer.

I think that the problem may be on my models but not sure what it is.

```
bundle\Entity\EntityOne:
    type: entity
    table: entityOne

    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        title:
            type: string
            length: '100'

    oneToMany:
        entityRel:
            targetEntity: EntityRel
            mappedBy: entityOne
            cascade: ["persist", "remove"]

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }



bundle\Entity\EntityRel:
    type: entity
    table: entityRel
    id:
        entityOne:
            associationKey: true
        entityTwo:
            associationKey: true
    fields:
        amount:
            type: decimal
    oneToOne:
        entityOne:
            targetEntity: EntityOne
        entityTwo:
            targetEntity: EntityTwo
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }



bundle\Entity\EntityTwo:
    type: entity
    table: entityTwo
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        name:
            type: string
            length: '100'

    oneToMany:
        entityRel:
            targetEntity: entityRel
            mappedBy: entityTwo
            cascade: ["persist", "remove"]

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

The idea is that EntityRel connects EntityOne and EntityTwo with an amount field. Each connection between the two tables must be unique thus enforcing the key to be composite.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you miss the EntityTwo's table:

```
bundle\Entity\EntityTwo:
type: entity
table: entityTwo
```

Comment: Hi, it was a typo on the code specification. The table definition is actually on each model. Any other idea? Thanks